# Meaning of the formula how to find lost element in array?

Tags: java, algorithm

The task is to find lost element in the array. I understand the logic of the solution but I don't understand how does this formula works?

Here is the solution

```
int[] array = new int[]{4,1,2,3,5,8,6};
   int size = array.length;
   int result = (size + 1) * (size + 2)/2;
   for (int i : array){
       result -= i;
   }
```

But why we add 1 to total size and multiply it to total size + 2 /2 ?? In all resources, people just use that formula but nobody explains how that formula works

Comment: The sum of all natural numbers from `1` up to `n`, so `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` can also be directly computed by `(n) * (n + 1) / 2`. See the very first paragraph in [Wikipedia#Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation).

Comment: The sequence in `array` is a broken sequence. It is **missing** one element (the `7`). But the sum formula talks about a **full sequence**. So `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` (8 numbers). The broken sequence has one too less (7 numbers), so you have to account for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum of the digits `1` thru `n` is equal to **((n)(n+1))/2**.

e.g. for 1,2,3,4,5  5*6/2 = 15.

But this is just a quick way to add up the numbers from `1` to `n`.  Here is what is really going on.

The series computes the sum of `1` to `n` assuming they all were present.  But by subtracting each number from that sum, the remainder is the missing number.

The formula for an arithmetic series of integers from `k` to `n` where adjacent elements differ by 1 is.

**S<sub>[k,n]</sub> = (n-k+1)(n+k)/2**

Example: k = 5, n = 10

- S<sub>[k,n]</sub> = 5   6  7  8  9 10
- S<sub>[k,n]</sub> = 10  9  8  7  6  5
- S<sub>[k,n]</sub> = (10-5+1)*(10+5)/2
- 2S<sub>[k,n]</sub> = 6 * 15 / 2
- S<sub>[k,n]</sub> = 90 / 2 = 45

For any single number missing from the sequence, by subtracting the others from the sum of 45, the remainder will be the missing number.

Comment: "And the reason length is 1 less than the numbers if they start by 1 is because arrays are zero based."

if this problem was in a language with 1-indexed arrays like lua or matlab the solution would be the same (you can try it out) so this isn't true

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you currently have n elements in your array. *You know*  that one element is  missing, which means that *the actual size* of your array should be n + 1.

Now, you just need to calculate the sum 1 + 2 + ... + n **+ (n+1)**.

A handy formula for computing the sum of all integers from 1 up to k is given by k(k+1)/2.

By just replacing k with n+1, you get the formula (n+1)(n+2)/2.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple mathematics.

Sum of first n natural numbers = n*(n+1)/2.

Number of elements in array = size of array.

So, in this case `n = size + 1`

So, after finding the sum, we are subtracting all the numbers from array individually and we are left with the missing number.

Comment: Your answer does not address the critical information OP did not spot, namely that the broken sequence (which is missing one number) has one size less than the full sequence, which he needs. So the reason why it is `n = size + 1` is missing and is what OP likely wants to have elaborated on.

Answer (score 1):

### Broken sequence vs full sequence

> But why we add 1 to total size and multiply it to total size + 2 /2 ?

The amount of numbers stored in your array is one less than the maximal number, as the sequence is **missing one element**.

Check your example:

```
4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 6
```

The sequence is supposed to go from `1` to `8`, but the amount of elements (`size`) is `7`, not `8`. Because the `7` is missing from the sequence.

Another example:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7
```

This sequence is missing the `4`. The full sequence would have a length of `7` but the above array would have a length of `6` only, one less.

You have to account for that and counter it.

---

### Sum formula

Knowing that, the sum of all natural numbers from `1` up to `n`, so `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` can also be directly computed by

```
n * (n + 1) / 2
```

See the very first paragraph in [Wikipedia#Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation).

But `n` is supposed to be `8` (length of the **full sequence**) in your example, not `7` (broken sequence). So you have to add `1` to all the `n` in the formula, receiving

```
(n + 1) * (n + 2) / 2
```

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire No.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be similar to [Missing Number of LeetCode (268)](https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/):

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public static int missingNumber(int[] nums) {
        int missing = nums.length;

        for (int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++)
            missing += index - nums[index];

        return missing;
    }
}
```

#### C++ using Bit Manipulation

```
class Solution {
public:
    int missingNumber(vector<int> &nums) {
        int missing = nums.size();
        int index = 0;

        for (int num : nums) {
            missing = missing ^ num ^ index;
            index++;
        }

        return missing;
    }
};
```

#### Python I

```
class Solution:
    def missingNumber(self, nums):
        return (len(nums) * (-~len(nums))) // 2 - sum(nums)
```

#### Python II

```
class Solution:
    def missingNumber(self, nums):
        return (len(nums) * ((-~len(nums))) >> 1) - sum(nums)
```

#### Reference to how it works:

The methods have been explained in the following links:

[Missing Number Discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

[Missing Number Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/solution/)